# How to revoke grants for a user with double quotes in it

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have mistakenly created and granted permissions to a user with double quotes in it in my mariadb database.

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select * from information_schema.user_privileges;

+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
| GRANTEE                              | TABLE_CATALOG | PRIVILEGE_TYPE          | IS_GRANTABLE |
+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
  ...                                                                                            
| '"bob@grr.la"'@'%'                   | def           | SELECT                  | NO           |
| '"bob@grr.la"'@'%'                   | def           | INSERT                  | NO           |
| '"bob@grr.la"'@'%'                   | def           | UPDATE                  | NO           |
| '"bob@grr.la"'@'%'                   | def           | DELETE                  | NO           |
  ...
+--------------------------------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

I have tried many different escape combinations but I don't seem to be able to target that user when I try to revoke privileges for it.

I have tried:

```
revoke all, grant option from '"bob@grr.la"'@'%';
revoke all, grant option from "bob@grr.la"@'%';
revoke all, grant option from \"bob@grr.la\"@'%';
revoke all, grant option from "%bob%"@'%';
revoke all, grant option from '%bob%'@'%';
```

None of those work. What gives?

Comment: Does it return a listing when you `SHOW GRANTS FOR '"bob@grr.la"'@'%'`?

Comment: The first method seems like it should work.

Comment: As a last resort you could just delete these rows from the `user_privileges` table, then use `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes, it does. I get 
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '"bob@grr.la"'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam`

Comment: @Barmar with the first method I get `There is no such grant defined for user '"bob@grr.la"' on host '%'`

Comment: You could also drop the user, then the grants associated with it are irrelevant.

Comment: Comment rather than solution, but why in the world would someone create a username like this? It's ridiculous.

Comment: @BillKarwin it's a fictional username, I needed that to be an email in order to map it with an LDAP directory user. If there is something wrong with the fact that it is an email address as an username then an advice on an alternative would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the double quote, e.g.:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create user '\"bob@grr.la\"'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> grant all on test.* to '\"bob@grr.la\"'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> revoke all privileges, grant option from '\"bob@grr.la\"'@'%';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: this did the trick, worth mentioning that although I think I tried it myself, I could not get it working because I deleted the user **before** removing privileges and grants. Nonetheless this is the right way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The `REVOKE` command must have exactly the same arguments that the `GRANT` had.  For example, `GRANT SELECT ...` is not undone by `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ...`